# How can I write an IME in MacOSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, internationalization, ime

I have a library which does transliteration between English & Indian languages.

I have created IMEs on Windows & Linux which uses this library. In Windows, I am using [Text Services Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and on Linux, it is done by creating a new engine to [ibus](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/). I'm wondering what would be the MacOSX way of doing an IME?

Comment: Apple does not provide an API to create third-party IMEs, which makes it very difficult to create IMEs on OS X. A Chinese company used to provide an IME called QIM, but it looks like they created their own architecture, with a background server that intercepts keyboard presses. It does not integrate with OS X's native IME system. http://download.cnet.com/IMKQIM/3000-2094_4-10648398.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [InputMethodKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-InputMethodKit/). There is a sample code available named [NumberInput_IMKit_Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NumberInput_IMKit_Sample/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. I will take a look at it.